# I need to implement a while loop with two conditions

Tags: c++

The following while loop has two conditions
cin >> user;

```
while (( user != 'X') || ( user != 'O'))
{
    cout << "Please enter either X or O " << endl;
    cin >> user;
}
```

After I enter either X or O, it keeps asking for a new input. I don't understand why? But if I remove on of the conditions it works properly.

Answer (score 4):

Think about the logic of "this thing is not X, or this thing is not Y" — barring overlaps between X and Y, such a condition is *always* true, even in English!

You've been misled by the colloquial and subtly different "this thing is neither X nor Y", but your code is *not* "neither X nor Y", but "not X or not Y".

What you meant was "not X and not Y".

```
while (( user != 'X') && ( user != 'O'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `&&` (and) instead of `||` (or).

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is always true...

```
while (( user != 'X') || ( user != 'O'))
```

If `user` is `'X'` then `user` is not `'O'` thus, even if the first part of the condition is not satisfied,  the second part of the condition is satisfied. So the whole condition is `true`.

Same thing if `user`is `'O'`.

Try this with a "logical and" (a.k.a. `&&`) instead of a "logical or".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want logical AND (`&&`) instead of logical OR (`||`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand what happens more intuitively, reverse the logic of your expression:

`!=` becomes `==`, and `||` (or) becomes `&&` (and).

So what you wrote is:

> Quit the loop if user equals 'X' AND user equals 'O'.

As you can see it's impossible for `user` to have both values at the same time.

What you want is:

```
while (( user != 'X') && ( user != 'O'))
{
    cout << "Please enter either X or O " << endl;
    cin >> user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `||` means or. If you read the condition aloud to yourself, it would sound like "While user is not X or user is not O. If you think about it, it will always be true - when it is X, it is also not O, and when it is O, it is not X. What you probably need is `&&`:

```
while (( user != 'X') && ( user != 'O'))
```

That way, the loop will stop when user is neither X nor O.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you're using the OR operator.

You're asking if user is not X or user is not O keep asking for input.

change it to && operator